# What does the "Tx" column mean in Electrum?

Tags: transactions, address, electrum, address-management

I found that there is a `Tx` column. For most of the addresses, the value in that column is 0.

For some addresses with balance greater than zero, it's not 0.

What does "tx" mean in this table?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In the context of Bitcoin, "tx" usually means transaction. In this specific context, it means the number of transactions that involve that address.

> It's weird, why there are some addresses with 0 balance have transactions?

A transaction can be receiving or sending Bitcoin. For addresses that were involved in transactions that now have a balance of 0, some transactions spent the remaining funds associated with those addresses.